# How to add more than one RSS Feed Link for wordpress

Tags: customization, links, rss, feed

I'm using code to change Rss Feed Link for my wordpress site, it's working but I don't know how to add more than one rss link appear when someone click on browser Rss Icon, I need these links to appear for all pages below each other for categories "products", "blog" and "news".

here is the code which I'm using to change my rss link

```
add_filter('feed_link','custom_feed_link', 1, 2);

function custom_feed_link($output, $feed) {

    $feed_url = 'http://MYSITE/category/products/feed';

    $feed_array = array('rss' => $feed_url, 'rss2' => $feed_url, 'atom' => $feed_url, 'rdf' => $feed_url, 'comments_rss2' => '');
    $feed_array[$feed] = $feed_url;
    $output = $feed_array[$feed];

    return $output;
}
```

I tried to return array, but it can't work, what I should do ?

[image]

Comment: what I need is to append selected categories feed link to appear when a user click on browser rss icon, same as attached image, so they can subscribe to any category feed which they prefer

Comment: I might have found solution to your problem, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Text that is displayed after you click on browser RSS icon depends on the feed reader you are using. I don't think you can modify what it displays directly through WordPress (correct me if I'm wrong).

A simple workaround to achieve something similar to what you want would be placing feed links to different categories. You can place a link for every category somewhere on the page using `get_category_feed_link()` function.

Edit:

Some feed readers (Chrome's RSS feed Reader) get feeds from sites header. In this case you can get them to display feed by adding link directly to `header.php` inside the `<head>`. Link could be formatted something like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Category1 feed" href="<?php echo get_category_feed_link( get_cat_ID( 'category1' ) ); ?>" />
```

Comment: @ IlmarsL Thank you for your reply I'm using similar method `<?php wp_list_categories('feed_image=http://SITE_URL/image.gif&feed=XML Feed&optioncount=1&children=0'); ?>` but my What I need is to append selected categories feed link to appear when a user click on browser rss icon, same as when you navigate to a post, you will find that its feed link's appended to site feed link, that's what I'm looking for